# How to create a gradient border as shown in image

Tags: html, css

[image]

I need to have border on two sides like this in a gradient way as shown here.However, My code looks like this:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  background: #ffffff;
}

.module-border-wrap {
  max-width: 320px;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #ffffff, #21BAE3);
  padding: 6px;
}

.module {
  background: #222;
  color: white;
  padding: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="module-border-wrap"><div class="module">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero pariatur corporis quaerat voluptatum eos tempora temporibus nisi voluptates sed, exercitationem sequi dolore culpa incidunt accusamus, quasi unde reprehenderit ea molestias.
</div></div>
```

How could I create a border as shown in image?

Comment: Have you try with conic-gradient?

Comment: Here is your answear https://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/MqMZGR

Comment: You can also play with an [online css generator](https://www.joshwcomeau.com/gradient-generator/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the gradient CSS a bit

```css
 body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  background: #ffffff;
}

.module-border-wrap {
  max-width: 320px;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(130deg, rgba(248,253,254,1) 50%, rgba(33,186,227,1) 100%);
  padding: 6px;
  border-radius: 1.5rem 1.5rem 0 1.5rem;
}

.module {
  background: #222;
  color: white;
  padding: 2rem;
  border-radius: 1.5rem 1.5rem 0 1.5rem;
}
  </style>
```

```html
<div class="module-border-wrap"><div class="module">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero pariatur corporis quaerat voluptatum eos tempora temporibus nisi voluptates sed, exercitationem sequi dolore culpa incidunt accusamus, quasi unde reprehenderit ea molestias.
  </div></div>
```

Comment: The issue with your solution is that using the same border radius in the .module class and the .module-border-wrap class gives you an uneven border thickness. You can see your rounded edges are slightly thicker than the straight sides.

Comment: Hello Biswajit and Adam, could you please help me on this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75052876/how-to-get-a-gradient-border-on-two-half-sides-of-a-image-as-shown-in-attached

Answer (score 1):

Use `background-origin: border-box;` then a transparent colour on your border. This will shift the background image to your border edge and be shown below your border.  overflow:hidden then clips the contents in your .module div correctly. See below.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  background: #ffffff;
}

.module-border-wrap {
  border-radius: 2rem 2rem 0 2rem;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, #25bae4 0%, #fff 55%, #fff 100%);
  background-origin: border-box;
  max-width: 320px;
}

.module {
  background: #222;
  color: white;
  padding: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="module-border-wrap"><div class="module">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero pariatur corporis quaerat voluptatum eos tempora temporibus nisi voluptates sed, exercitationem sequi dolore culpa incidunt accusamus, quasi unde reprehenderit ea molestias.
</div></div>
```

Comment: instead of showing half border on left side, can't we stop / make white starts from half on the bottom border? Could you please let me know how to fix, this, blue is extending quite more than needed.

Comment: For sure. You can use stops in the linear gradient to give you the exact location where the colour transitions start (see here https://css-tricks.com/books/greatest-css-tricks/hard-stop-gradients/ ). Where do you wan the blue on the right to fade out? Is the current location okay?

Comment: its showing same old gradient, I have attached image of desired gradient.

Comment: I've tweaked it slightly and added an extra stop in the background-image: property. Feel free to tweak. There's a handy generator here https://cssgradient.io/

Comment: could you please help me on this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75052876/how-to-get-a-gradient-border-on-two-half-sides-of-a-image-as-shown-in-attached