# How to get a gradient border on two half sides of a image, as shown in attached image

Tags: html, css

My code:

```css
 body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  background: #000000;
}

.module-border-wrap {
  max-width: 320px;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(130deg, rgba(248,253,254,1) 50%, rgba(33,186,227,1) 100%);
  padding: 6px;
  border-radius: 1.5rem 1.5rem 0 1.5rem;
}

.module {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 2rem;
  border-radius: 1.5rem 1.5rem 0 1.5rem;
}

.w-100{
  width:100;
}
.p-0{
  padding:0;
}
.relative{
  position: relative;
}
.curved{
  border-radius: 30px 30px 0 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="module-border-wrap">
   <div class="module p-0 relative curved">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" class="w-100 curved" alt="">
   </div>
</div>
```

So far, I am able to get the gradient, however, its showing outside of image, unlike in the attached screenshot, where the gradient border is over the image itself.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0hL213uv/20/)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can try using one pseudo element and multiple backgrounds

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  background: #000000;
}

.box {
  border-radius: 1.5rem 1.5rem 0 1.5rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  inset: 0;
  --g: #0000 1.8rem,#21bae3; /* update the color here */
  --t: 10px; /* the thickness of the gradient */
  background:
   linear-gradient( 90deg,var(--g)) bottom/100% var(--t),
   linear-gradient(180deg,var(--g)) right /var(--t) 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200"  >
</div>
```